# Those who observe "Ben Zachar" at night and "Shalom Zachar" by day

Tags: halacha, minhag, baby-infant

There's a pretty common custom to observe what's commonly called a "*Shalom Zachar*" on the Friday night after a baby boy is born. People go to where the baby's father is, eat snacks, sing and share *divrei Torah*. This seems to be based on what the **Rema** ([*Yoreh Deah* 265:12, see the **Taz** *ad. loc.* § 13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.265.12?lang=he&p2=Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.265.13&lang2=he)) brings.

The **Aruch HaShulchan** ([*ad. loc.* § 37](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.265.37?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) says in his day the custom was to do the above mentioned custom on Friday night and call it "*Ben Zachar*". Whereas, the next day they visit the mother and wish her *mazal tov*, and don't eat anything. They call this a "*Shalom Zachar*".

> נהגו לעשות סעודה ומשתה בליל שבת לאחר שנולד זכר, נכנסים אצל התינוק לטעום שם, והוא גם כן סעודת מצוה...ובאמת אין המנהג בסעודה, רק בטעימת פירות, **וקורין זה "בן זכר"**. **ולמחרת בשבת** אחר התפילה נכנסים אצל היולדת ליתן "מזל טוב", **וקורין לזה "שלום זכר"**. ונוהגין שלא לטעום כלום, ואומרים שזהו מתקנת המדינה לבלי להכביד על הבעל ברית.

I've never heard of this version of the custom. Are there any communities today that observe it/refer to it as the **Aruch HaShulchan** describes?

Comment: In Frankfurt, as well as other Rheinland Jewish communities, the custom was simply to call the se'udah a "zochor". I can't speak to the custom of the 'Aruch haShulchan, though

Comment: I'm gonna try to find exactly where it is but there is something in likkutei dibburim about a shalom zachor and then next day about a shalom ben zachor